Datatype for incomplete date in Java for MySQL
I'm aiming to store incomplete dates (for example, only MM-YYYY) to represent card expiry years in MySQL (version 8.0 or above).
In MySQL (>=8.0), it supports partial date.

Ranges for the month and day specifiers begin with zero due to the fact that MySQL permits the storing of incomplete dates such as '2014-00-00'.

Now, I need to access this column in my Java Spring Boot application and create a Java Class Entity to represent the table containing this column. However, I'm struggling to find a suitable predefined class or data type to represent MySQL incomplete dates. This class or data type should facilitate assigning values while storing and retrieving data from the database.
One option is to use the String data type, but this would relax the constraint of it being a valid date format. Can anyone suggest a suitable predefined class, data type or any other standard implementation for this scenario?
Simplified create table syntax:
CREATE TABLE `Card` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

I've already looked into other similar questions this and this, but they didn't provide an answer to my specific query.

COuld you add the entity class code you created for this table?

@F.Igor I haven't still created, currently exploring the best way. You can consider simplified structure like this
@Data
public class Card {
  private String number;
  private String expiryDate;
}

Here for expiry date I looking suitable datatype.

FYI, YearMonth class is built into Java 8+. But not mapped in JDBC.

By the way, the standard ISO 8601 format for representing a year-with-month textually is YYYY-MM.

Wouldn't that expiry date actually be a complete LocalDate (the end of the month)? IOW YearMonth.parse("2024-04").atEndOfMonth();

@g00se yeah the end of the month will mean the same value, however it will change the actual representation, which is not expectation here.

Why would that matter, you're going to have to calculate with the 'real' value anyway, most probably

@g00se It matters because of business usecase, where it's view is directly accessible to some ops team member. Keeping it non zero will point to some date which could create ambiguity since card provider doesn't provide day in expiry date. Keeping it zero as day means it is missing value, which makes sense in this use case.

YearMonth worked in my case. However it is not mapped to JDBC directly, I used converter for mapping.
Sample Code:
Entity
public class Card {
  private String number;
  @Convert(converter = YearMonthConverter.class)
  private YearMonth expiry;
}

Converter
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class YearMonthConverter implements AttributeConverter<YearMonth, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(YearMonth yearMonth) {
    if (yearMonth != null) {
      int year = yearMonth.getYear();
      int month = yearMonth.getMonthValue();
      return String.format("%d-%02d-00", year, month);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public YearMonth convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    if (dbData != null) {
      String[] parts = dbData.split("-");
      int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
      int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
      return YearMonth.of(year, month);
    }
    return null;
  }
}


I must say I don't understand. If you're storing in the db as some kind of char type, why do you add zeros to the end?

@g00se If you don't undertand why adding zeros in code before storing then I would say it is to support MySQL incomplete date syntax, link given in question. If you don't understand the usecase why storing zero as day in table not last day of month then it is because of simplicity and clear understanding that day is meaningless here. I have updated the question with simplified table schema.

For conversion from String I suggest YearMonth.parse(daData, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM'-00'")).

Ok. I thought you were using a char type

@g00se I think I would use a char (or varchar) type if I hadn’t got a requirement to do date operation on the value in SQL. And then obviously not append -00. For some applications the ability to do SQL date operations is convenient (and also in SQL you can append -00 on the fly and convert, but it’s a bit more cumbersome and expensive).

My general point is that it seems the natural thing to do to store LocalDate since that is the real value that will be used to calculate expiry issues
